What's the difference of "was" as Nebensatz (as Object) or Relativsatz (as Attributive)?

Man lernt, was es bedeutet, sich fremd zu fühlen.
Man lernt das, was es bedeutet, sich fremd zu fühlen.
Man lernt, was es bedeutet, dass man sich fremd fühlt.
Man lernt das, was es bedeutet, dass man sich fremd fühlt.

I cannot tell the difference “was” as Nebensatz (as Object) or Relativsatz (as Attributive). The first sentence is from the Studio [21] B1 (page 170 line 36), and the last three are written by me.
My question is: 1) Are those four sentences grammatically correct? 2) What's the differences in the meaning?

Was is a relative pronoun introducing a relative clause in all these sentences. The difference beween these sentences has nothing to do with the function of was.

As an aside: You replaced zu-infinitive with finite dass-clauses after "bedeuten" in your example set - this is sometimes possible, sometimes less good, but it is something that is a separate issue from the question you are asking. You announced a question about "was"-clauses.
The tricky thing is that there are two types of clauses introduced by "was", or other w-words. It can be a relative clause or an indirect question. Here is how they differ:
Example 1: "you learn what it means..." is actually an indirect question. There's a question around: "What does it mean / What is it like ...to feel alien?" You have learnt to answer that question. This is why the construction with "das, was" is not possible here, because this instance of "was" would introduce a relative clause that depends on "das".
An example of a relative clause as an object would be

Sie lernt jetzt (das), was sie schon immer wissen wollte.

Here, someone is learning something: those things which she had always wanted to know. Here, the "was-"clause is a relative clause. In this case, the object can also be expressed as "das, was...".
I think there is also a subtle difference in the verb meaning, which may help clarify the difference. In the first example, the meaning of "lernen" is "to come to know". So, people may wonder what it is like to feel alien, and you have now found out. It is indefinite what it is, there were different possibilities, but now you know what it is. -- In the other use, the meaning of "lernen" is rather "to study". Someone is studying something. And that (specific) thing is something they had always wanted to know.
So the important difference is that the relative clause refers to a "thing", while the indirect question refers to a set of possibilities (that can be expressed by different sentences, and you have to pick one as an answer).
